# Best Method to pass a variable and it's value instantiated in one class to another class

Tags: java, selenium

I am an Automation Quality Assurance engineer and I am using Eclipse, java, and selenium to do the majority of my automation.  Right now I am scripting tests that include generating a unique number as a type of user (user 1) and then searching for that specific number as another type of user (user 2)

The methods/actions of the user types are separated into different classes and both are referenced in the test class. This is the unique number being identified and stored as a variable (srnumber 2) in the user 1 class.

```
    public class InvoicingPOF {
        @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelSRNumberHeader")
        WebElement SRNumberBillingReq;

        public void InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion(String Srnumber) throws InterruptedException {
            CreateInvoicebtn.click();
            String srnumber2 = SRNumberBillingReq.getText(); //Example of getting Service request number in invoice class 
            InvoiceNumberfield.sendKeys(srnumber2);
            InvoiceAmount.sendKeys("0.00");
            WorkDateField.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            TodaysDatebtn.click();
            WorkDateField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            CustomerSignatureQuestion.sendKeys("Y", Keys.TAB);
            NextStep1.click();

        }

}
```

I want to take that srnumber2 variable and the value (lets say the number generated is 1234 I want to pass that to another class) in user 1's class (InvoicingPOF) and use it in User 2's class (HomePagePOFSC).  Below is the rest of the code

```
Test Class

  package fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import pageobjectfactory.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;

public class E2ESRInvoiceTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    Ourfsnlogin LoginPage;
    SRCreate SRCreatePage;
    InvoicingPOF Invoicing;
    HomePagePOF HomePage;

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws InterruptedException {
        SRCreate.webdrive();
        InvoicingPOF.webdrive();
        // SRCreate.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // setting global explicit wait
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(InvoicingPOF.driver, 60), this);
        InvoicingPOF.driver.get("fsndevweb:81");
        // initiating elements in page factory
        SRCreatePage = PageFactory.initElements(InvoicingPOF.driver, SRCreate.class);
        LoginPage = PageFactory.initElements(InvoicingPOF.driver, Ourfsnlogin.class);
        Invoicing = PageFactory.initElements(InvoicingPOF.driver, InvoicingPOF.class);
        HomePage = PageFactory.initElements(InvoicingPOF.driver, HomePagePOF.class);

        LoginPage.sendUserName("ebluth");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.USclick();
        SRCreatePage.NavigateToSRCreatebtn();
        SRCreatePage.SRCreationTestHVAC();
        String srnumber = SRCreatePage.SRNumber.getText();
        System.out.println(srnumber + " it worked !");
        LoginPage.Logout();
        LoginPage.sendUserNameSP("4335701");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.SPSRSearch(srnumber);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Invoicing.ActivtityCompletition();
        HomePage.HomePageNaviate();
        LoginPage.SPSRSearch(srnumber);

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void SPInvoiceSubmissionTest() throws InterruptedException {
        String Srnumber = null;
        Invoicing.InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion(Srnumber);
        Invoicing.SPInvoiceWorkPerformed();
        Invoicing.SPInvoiceLaboraPartsandSummary();
        Invoicing.SPInvoiceAttachment();
        Invoicing.InvoiceConfirmation();
        LoginPage.LogoutSP();

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void SCInvoiceSubmissionTest() throws InterruptedException {
        String Srnumber = null;
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        LoginPage.sendUserNameServiceCenter("SCUser");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        //Service Request search action would happen here 

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();

    }

}

Relevant Page Object Classes 
package pageobjectfactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

public class InvoicingPOF {
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibSRNum")
    WebElement SPSRSearchbtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbSRNum")
    WebElement SPSRSearchbox;

    // Activity Management
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_checkInButton")
    WebElement CheckinBtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_checkOutButton")
    WebElement CheckOutBtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ddlCompleted")
    WebElement JobCompleteDropDown;
    @FindBy(id = "ifrmManageActivity")
    WebElement ManageActivityBox;

    @FindBy(id = "txtETA")
    WebElement ETABox;
    @FindBy(id = "TextboxSRNote")
    WebElement TextBoxSRNote;
    @FindBy(id = "txtTimeIn")
    WebElement TimeinBox;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_timeInRepair")
    WebElement Timeinstamp;
    @FindBy(id = "txtTimeOut")
    WebElement TimeoutBox;
    @FindBy(id = "txtReturnETA")
    WebElement ReturnETABox;
    @FindBy(id = "btnSave")
    WebElement SavebtnActivityPopup;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptrSRData_ctl01_hlSR#")
    WebElement SRListSelect;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_createInvoiceButton")
    WebElement CreateInvoicebtn;

    // Invoice Module Billing Requirements
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextboxInvNum")
    WebElement InvoiceNumberfield;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextboxInvAmt")
    WebElement InvoiceAmount;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelSiteLimit")
    WebElement NTE;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropdownlistSignature")
    WebElement CustomerSignatureDropDown;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextboxWorkDate")
    WebElement WorkDateField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='datepick-current']/a")
    WebElement TodaysDatebtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelSRNumberHeader")
    WebElement SRNumberBillingReq;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropdownlistSignature")
    WebElement CustomerSignatureQuestion;
    // Remember to include work date alert acceptance before proceeding to step

    // Invoice SP Labor and Taxes
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor_ctl02_ddlLabor")
    WebElement LabortypeDD;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor_ctl02_txtQty")
    WebElement HoursSP;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor_ctl02_btnEdit")
    WebElement EditbtnLabor;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor_ctl02_btnUpdate")
    WebElement UpdatebtnLabor;

    // Invoicing Steps Work Performed.Assets.Parts
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@href,'Edit$0')]")
    WebElement Editbtn0;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@onclick,'Update$0')]")
    WebElement Updatebtn0;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@href,'Edit$1')]")
    WebElement Editbtn1;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@onclick,'Update$1')]")
    WebElement Updatebtn1;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@href,'Edit$2')]")
    WebElement Editbtn2;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@onclick,'Update$2')]")
    WebElement Updatebtn2;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_workDonePartsUsed_gridWorkPerf_ctl02_DropdownlistEquipment ")
    WebElement AssetDropDownWrkPerformed;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@onclick,'workperf')]")
    WebElement AddNewWorkPerformedbtn;
    @FindBy(id = "frameAddWPorParts ")
    WebElement AddNewWorkSearchFrame;
    // navigate to asset with keyboard commands, select using enter

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_btnEdit")
    WebElement LaborEditbtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_btnUpdate ")
    WebElement LaborUpdatebtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_ddlLabor")
    WebElement LaborTypeDD;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_txtSCQty")
    WebElement SCHours;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_txtSCRate")
    WebElement SCRate;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_txtCustQty")
    WebElement CustomerHours;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_laborTaxes_gridLabor_ctl02_txtCustRate")
    WebElement CustomerRate;

    @FindBy(id = "btnSearch")
    WebElement SearcbtnAddNewWork;
    // Will have to use keyboard commands to navigate to the first asset type
    @FindBy(id = "ui-id-216-button")
    WebElement AssetSelection;
    // Will have to use keyboard commands to navigate to the first asset
    // selection
    @FindBy(id = "btnAddCheckedItems ")
    WebElement AddCheckeditemsbtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_workDonePartsUsed_btnCloseAddWPorParts")
    WebElement CloseWindowbtn;

    // RTPSpecificObjects

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSRNumber")
    WebElement SRSearchRTP;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnYes")
    WebElement YesContinueInvoice;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnYes")
    WebElement YesPaperWorkMatch;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkAttach")
    WebElement InvoiceAttachmentrtpbtn;
    // InvoiceAttachment
    @FindBy(id = "frmShowAttachment")
    WebElement FileAttachmentFrame;
    @FindBy(id = "attachment")
    WebElement Choosefilebtn;
    //Submit invoice 


    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='InvoicingContainer']/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]")
    WebElement SubmitInvoicebtn;


    // Need additional research on attaching files
    @FindBy(id = "ImageNext")
    WebElement Nextbtnframe;
    @FindBy(id = "btnShowAttachmentClose")
    WebElement CloseFileAttachWindow;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageNext")
    WebElement NextStep1;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkAccept")
    WebElement AcceptCalculatedAmountSelection;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_finalValidation_chkAcceptDiff")
    WebElement InvoiceVarianceAcceptanceCheckBox;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_attachment")
    WebElement InvoiceAttachmenttbnSP;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageSubmit")
    WebElement SubmitInvoice;
    // Confirmation page
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_lblNoPaymentReferenceNumber")
    WebElement InvoiceReferenceNumber;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_lblSRNumber")
    WebElement SRNumberConfirmationPage;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridWork']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")
    WebElement WorkPerformedConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridWork']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
    WebElement AssetConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridLaborServiceCenterView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='GridViewWideColumn']]")
    WebElement LaborTypeConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridLaborServiceCenterView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][1]")
    WebElement HoursConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridLaborServiceCenterView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][2]")
    WebElement SystemRateConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridLaborServiceCenterView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][3]")
    WebElement RequestedRateConfirmationPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_gridLaborServiceCenterView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][4]")
    WebElement RequestedRate;









    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void webdrive() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\dmohamed\\Documents\\Testing Environment\\Testing Environment\\Web Drivers\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver chromedriver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver = chromedriver;

    }

    public void SPSRSearch(String srnumber) {
        SPSRSearchbox.sendKeys(srnumber);
        SPSRSearchbtn.click();

    }

    public void SRSelect() {

        SRListSelect.click();

    }

    public void ActivtityCompletition() throws InterruptedException {
        CheckinBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String Timein = Timeinstamp.getText();
        CheckOutBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Alert savealert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        savealert.accept();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(ManageActivityBox);
        ETABox.clear();
        ETABox.sendKeys(Timein);
        /*
         * //Thread.sleep(2000); TimeinBox.clear();
         * TimeinBox.sendKeys("8/1/2016 1:35:00 PM"); //Thread.sleep(2000);
         * TimeoutBox.clear(); TimeoutBox.sendKeys("8/1/2016 1:40:00 PM");
         * //Thread.sleep(2000);
         */
        JobCompleteDropDown.sendKeys("y");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        TextBoxSRNote.sendKeys("test");
        SavebtnActivityPopup.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        SavebtnActivityPopup.click();

    }



    public void InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion(String Srnumber) throws InterruptedException {
        CreateInvoicebtn.click();
        String srnumber2 = SRNumberBillingReq.getText(); //Example of getting Service request number in invoice class 
        InvoiceNumberfield.sendKeys(srnumber2);
        InvoiceAmount.sendKeys("0.00");
        WorkDateField.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        TodaysDatebtn.click();
        WorkDateField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        CustomerSignatureQuestion.sendKeys("Y", Keys.TAB);
        NextStep1.click();

    }



    public void SPInvoiceWorkPerformed() throws InterruptedException {

        Editbtn0.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        /*
         * if (isAlertPresent()) { driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); }
         */
        Updatebtn0.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        NextStep1.click();

    }

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSubTotal")
    WebElement LaborTotal;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTaxS")
    WebElement TaxAmt;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTotal")
    WebElement LaborTaxTotal;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor_ctl02_txtRate")
    WebElement RateSP;
    //*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][1]
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridLabor']/tbody/tr[2]/td[@class='NumericCell'][1]")
    WebElement HoursSPInput;

    public void SPInvoiceLaboraPartsandSummary() throws InterruptedException {
        EditbtnLabor.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        HoursSP.clear();
        HoursSP.sendKeys("1");
        UpdatebtnLabor.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        double LaborHours = Double.parseDouble(HoursSPInput.getText());
        System.out.println(LaborHours);
        String LaborValue = RateSP.getAttribute("value");
        String LaborValue1 = LaborValue.replace("$", "");
        System.out.println(LaborValue1);
        double LaborRate = Double.parseDouble(LaborValue1);
        String SPTotalValue = LaborTotal.getAttribute("value");
        String SPTotalValue1= SPTotalValue.replace("$", "");
        double SPTotal = Double.parseDouble(SPTotalValue1);
        Assert.assertTrue(LaborHours*LaborRate==SPTotal, "Labor Total Mismatch");

        String Taxvalue = TaxAmt.getText();
        if (TaxAmt.getText().contains("N/A")){
            String TaxRealValue=Taxvalue.replace("N/A", "0");
            double Tax= Double.parseDouble(TaxRealValue);
            String TotalLaborTax = LaborTaxTotal.getAttribute("value");
            String TotalLaborTax1= TotalLaborTax.replace("$", "");
            double Total = Double.parseDouble(TotalLaborTax1);


            Assert.assertTrue(SPTotal+Tax==Total, "Labor + Tax Mismatch");
            System.out.println(SPTotal+Tax +"  Sum of Labor and Taxes ");
            System.out.println( Total + "  MyFSN Calculation");
        }
        else {
        //String TaxRealValue=Taxvalue.replace("N/A", "0");
        double Tax= Double.parseDouble(Taxvalue);
        String TotalLaborTax = LaborTaxTotal.getAttribute("value");
        String TotalLaborTax1= TotalLaborTax.replace("$", "");
        double Total = Double.parseDouble(TotalLaborTax1);
        Assert.assertTrue(SPTotal+Tax==Total, "Labor + Tax Mismatch");
        }

        NextStep1.click();
        NextStep1.click();
        AcceptCalculatedAmountSelection.click();



    }

    public void SPInvoiceAttachment() {
    InvoiceAttachmenttbnSP.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\dmohamed\\Desktop\\testPDF.pdf");
    NextStep1.click();
    SubmitInvoicebtn.click();
    }

    //InvoiceConfirmation 
    @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_pnlLegacyMessage']/strong[1]")
    WebElement InvoiceConfirmationMessage;
    @FindBy(id= "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_lblSCInvoiceNumber")
    WebElement SRNumberInvoiceConfirmation;
    @FindBy(id= "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSummary_lblGrandTotal")
    WebElement InvoiceTotalConfirmation;

    public void InvoiceConfirmation () throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if (InvoiceConfirmationMessage.getText().contains("You have successfully submitted your invoice ")) {
    System.out.println("MyFSN SP invoice submission successful");   
    }
    else {
    Assert.fail("MyFSN SP invoice submission failed");
    }
    String Srnumber3 = SRNumberInvoiceConfirmation.getText();
    System.out.println(Srnumber3);
    }



}


package pageobjectfactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;



public class HomePagePOFSC {
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_0")
    WebElement Home;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_1")
    WebElement Inventory;

    // InventorySublinks
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_2")
    WebElement Cyclecount;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_3")
    WebElement PartsOnHand;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_4")
    WebElement TransactionSearch;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_5")
    WebElement ParManagement;
    // InventorySublinks

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_6")
    WebElement Orders;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_7")
    WebElement Queues;

    // Queue Sublinks
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_8")
    WebElement InvoiceQueue;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_9")
    WebElement QuoteQue;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_10")
    WebElement RequisitionQueue;
    // Queue Sublinks

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_11")
    WebElement MyAccount;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_12")
    WebElement CreateNewSRlink;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_13")
    WebElement PrintVouchers;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_14")
    WebElement Tools;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_Menu1_29")
    WebElement Logout;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSRNumber")
    WebElement SRSearchfield;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnViewSR")
    WebElement SRSearchBtn;
    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlButtons")
    WebElement ProcessSRAsContractorbtn;


    public void NavigateToInvoice() {

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(Queues).perform();
            WebElement subElement = InvoiceQueue;
            action.moveToElement(subElement);
            action.click();
            action.perform();
            //Would search for service request at this point 


    }
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void webdrive() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\dmohamed\\Documents\\Testing Environment\\Testing Environment\\Web Drivers\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver chromedriver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver = chromedriver;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It's hard to see what the actual question here is. Can you please try to refactor your question to make it really precise, perhaps with a short code example of where you are struggling, and i'll gladly try to help.

Comment: Can you possibly add the relevant code and HTML page source?

Comment: @ThePerson I tried to clarify what I meant, see the updated OP

Comment: I'm still a bit lost i'm afraid. However, can't InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion just return the value that you want rather than void?

Comment: It is still very difficult to understand what you're asking. I don't understand your explanation regarding the "generation" when looking at the initial bit of code. As for the super-long code segment afterwards - TL;DR. Try to create a _minimal_ code sample illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the method `InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion()` to return the variable you want and passing it to your actual test by just calling the method and assign it to a var like this:

```
String var = InvoicingPOF.InvoiceBillingRequirementCompletion(x);
```